# XML processing and creating a resource in parallel in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am writing a app, which has to create multiple Resources. The input is a XML. I need to parse the XML, create the Resources in parallel and update the responses in the Ouputs.

```
<Components>
    <Resources>
        <CreateResourceARequest> ...</CreateResourceARequest>
        <CreateResourceBRequest>...</CreateResourceBRequest>
        <CreateResourceCRequest>...</CreateResourceCRequest>
    </Resources>
    <Outputs>
        <CreateResourceAResponse>...</CreateResourceAResponse>
        <CreateResourceBResponse>...</CreateResourceBResponse>
        <CreateResourceCResponse>...</CreateResourceCResponse>
    </Outputs>
<Components>
```

Each of the `ResourceRequests` are handled by a specific Classes.

What is the best way to create Resources in parallel, aggregate the results and update the xml ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "in parallel" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will parse xml file in single thread anyway because the file is linear. but you can collect you parsers for each  CreateResourceCRequest in a set and start them all in parallel threads after parsing file

Comment: sometimes I need to ensure that a resource needs to be created before other resources are created. How do I ensure that ?

Comment: exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
exec.execute(new CreateResourceA(input));
exec.execute(new CreateResourceB(input));
exec.execute(new CreateResourceB(input));
exec.shutdown();   
while (!exec.isTerminated()){
   logger.debug("some tasks are still running");
}  ----- currently I am doing it this way, but this does not ensure ResourceA to be created before ResourceB.